# Cygwin - updating an old verison of g++

Tags: cygwin, g++

I installed Cygwin but it appears the mirror I chose my packages from had very old versions on it. I am running g++ 3.4.4 but the latest release is 4.8.0

Whenever I went on the g++ website the .tar's they had for 4.8 were ~100MB; I downloaded and it contained thousands of files. I thought all I had to do was replace g++.exe from Cygwin's /bin/ directory, but it appears it's more complicated.

Or am I missing something / is there an easier way?

Comment: Why don't you run the cygwin `setup.exe` again and choose a different mirror? If you just click through, _all_ your installed packages get updated. This usually works flawlessly for me, but I don't know for sure, if it works if you upgrade from such an old version. Reinstallation is no possibility?

Comment: The only thing for download at the GCC web site is the source code. They link to sites with binaries [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/binaries.html) including [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=gcc).

Comment: Btw, the current version of `g++` in the cygwin repo is 4.5.3 (updated just now via "TU Dresden" mirror.)

Answer (score 1):

The `gcc4-*` packages currently provide the 4.x versions of GCC.  4.7.2 is currently available as a test release, which can be installed in `setup.exe` by toggling the version number of **each** of the `gcc4-*` packages until the 4.7.2 version is indicated.